# What'd be the synthetically correct way of imitating extendable enum behavior?

Tags: java, enums, constants

Traditionally, when I have an enum:

```java
public enum SomeEnum implements Serializable {
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2;
}
```

or a class:

```java
public class Country {

    public static final Country SOME_COUNTRY = new Country("someCode");

    private final String code;

    ...
}
```

In a controller, I return these values to populate some selects:

```java
@RestController(...)
public List<Field> getFields() {

    return Arrays.asList(SomeEnum.class.getEnumConstants());

    // or

    return Arrays.asList(Country.class.getDeclaredFields());
}
```

Currently, I'm working on a webhook library which could be imported by some final products. Some of the event names come from the library itself but some of them are not present in the library (but in the final product code):

`Webhook` class looks like this:

```java
public class Webhook {

    private String url;

    private List<WebhookEvent> events;

    ...
}
```

and `WebhookEvent` is as follows:

```java
public class WebhookEvent Serializable {

    private long id;

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

and the `WebhookEvent`s are populated from the database. I **don't want** to create a holding class in the final product like:

```java
public class EnabledEvent {

    public static final WebhookEvent SOME_EVENT = new WebhookEvent("event.name");

    ...
}
```

because that'd be controlling the behavior of the application from 2 different points. But instead, I want to be able to return these constants/fields as soon as there's a new entry in the database. Basically I want to be able to imitate the behavior of extend the constants/enums based on the entries in the database. Is there a correct way to programmatically achieve this?

Comment: In a project we had the a similar list of `enums` that we had to put in database and fetch later, but some types had less elements so we ended up using both ways(at least saved some calls to db).

Comment: I'd very much like to see how you'd go without saving the calls to the database. Can you show an example? A db call can pretty much always be easily avoided with caching in this scenario.

Comment: Tried to summarize it in an answer, let me know in case there are things to improve from your point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up removing the connection with the database, and defining static variables within the class itself, with a static `ofValue` method to create objects:

```
public class SomeClass implements Serializable {

    public static final SomeClass MY_CONSTANT_1 = new SomeClass("static.value");

    public static SomeClass [] values = new SomeClass []{
            SomeClass .MY_CONSTANT_1,
            ...
    };

    private String name;

    public SomeClass (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static SomeClass ofValue(String name){
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) return null;
        for(SomeClass value : values) if(value .getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) return event;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Couldn't convert value : %s into a valid %s object", name, SomeClass.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

this way, it is expandable as follows:

```java
public class ExtendedSomeClass extends SomeClass implements Serializable {

    public static final SomeClass MY_CONSTANT_2 = new SomeClass ("static.value.2");

    public static SomeClass[] values = new SomeClass[]{
            SomeClass.MY_CONSTANT_2,
    };

    public static SomeClass ofValue(String name){
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) return null;
        for(SomeClass event : values) if(event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) return event;
        return SomeClass.ofEvent(name);
    }
}
```

and I can always concatenate `values` arrays and return it from a `@RestController` endpoint to populate forms.

Answer (score 0):

In our case there were many constants that we had to validate. This constant files started to pile up. So, we had to devise a different way and ended up creating a separate table only for constants, so you can add or remove/disable the not required once without the need to recompile your code(though you have to, if there is a dependent case).

For instance, assume that you have the following patient status (STATUS):

*STABLE, CRITICAL, DECEASED, RECOVERED and NA*

and the following states for TEST_RESULT:

*TEST_PENDING, TEST_NEGATIVE and TEST_POSITIVE*

The table would look like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
enum_code       enum_type       enum_name       enum_desc       disabled
------------------------------------------------------------------------
001             STATUS          STABLE                          false
002             STATUS          CRITICAL                        false
003             STATUS          DECEASED                        false
004             STATUS          RECOVERED                       false
005             STATUS          NA                              false
100             TEST_RESULT     TEST_PENDING                    false
101             TEST_RESULT     TEST_NEGATIVE                   false
102             TEST_RESULT     TEST_POSITIVE                   false
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="constant_enum")
public class ConstantEnum implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="enum_code")
    private Integer enumCode;
    
    private boolean disabled;
    
    @Column(name="enum_desc")
    private String enumDesc;
    
    
    @Column(name="enum_name")
    private String enumName;

    @Column(name="enum_type") // this is the discriminator
    private String enumType;
    
    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: I see, but the question starts here. This is also what I got at the moment. How do I list them as constants is the question.

Comment: Well I understood your question in a wrong way then. I would love to see other options popup, it would be very helpful

Comment: fyi this kind of table is something DBAs classify as an antipattern, it's called the One True Lookup Table.

Comment: @NathanHughes are you a DBA, or shat is your opinion on this particular case?

Comment: @NathanHughes I was not planning on keeping every `enum` in one huge DB table, instead a single enum in a single table, so I'm guessing that this comment was not applicable to my case. Thanks anyways!